# How to export a Data frame as a CSV with a randomly generated name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with some data (UCAS applications) and need to write a code that will anonymise everything by taking personal data out of it. Once my code has removed all this personal data I would like to export it into an excel file (CSV or xlsx either is fine) which has a randomly generated name.

The namegenerator module works perfectly, however, I'm having issues actually exporting the file into the correct form.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(result_data)

random_name=namegenerator.gen()
df.to_csv(random_name, index=False, header=False)
```

The file is being exported with a random name correctly however it is of the wrong type. It's just a file rather than a CSV.

Comment: Are you saying it lacks the file extension `'.csv'`? Just append this to your `random_name`

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite new to python so not 100% sure what you mean. When my file is exported it isn't being exported in the desired form. I've tried simply just adding 'csv' to the end of random name however it's throwing me this error     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'csv'

Comment: No you want `df.to_csv(random_name + '.csv', index=False, header=False) `, you're trying to build a new string for the filename

Comment: That has worked! Thankyou for the help and speedy reply

Comment: @ConnorGill a CSV file *is* just a text file, with a specific format. The extension doesn't mean anything. It's still nothing more than a text file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would argue the other way around: a CSV file is a CSV file no matter the file name extension and it is never just a text file, even if you name it _something.txt_. Otherwise every file is just a binary file, even if it just contains just byte values in the ASCII range that form sensible words, paragraphs, and so on, it's still nothing more than a binary file. 

Answer (score 3):

You need to append the extension `'.csv'` to your generated filename:

```
df.to_csv(random_name + '.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

What you did was to write a file with a name `random_name` without any `'.csv'` extension

Note that `pandas` and most decent csv readers, would still have been able to read this file even without the `'.csv'` extension:

```
pd.read_csv(random_name)
```

would have still worked